# Why do packages fail to install from command line

Tags: package-management, software-center

Every once in a while I can't install packages in Ubuntu 11.04. I'll try to run the software center and it and it will pop up then disappear. If I call it from the command line it says it seg-faults. And then trying to install anything from the command line I get this:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
Reading package lists... Done
```

And thats all I get for anything I try. Usually restarting fixes the problem but its very annoying.

Comment: Does running `aptitude`instead of `apt-get`gives you the same results?

Comment: Its not installed and I can't install it for the same reason.

Comment: what happens if you do a apt-get update

Comment: That did it, never thought about doing it. thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `/var/log/apt/*.log` and `/var/log/dpkg.log`? Maybe there's some information there that can be used to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Random segfaults that go away when you reboot?  Could be a hardware issue.  Run memtest86 for a few hours, see if any errors show up.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to cosmorogers for the super easy answer of:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: if an apt-get update solved your problem, then the actual problem was that some part of your ubuntu install was still an old version that didn't match up with what your version of apt-get needed.